# Is there an implementation of javax.bluetooth.* that works on El Capitan?

Tags: java, bluetooth, osx-elcapitan, bluecove

It appears that BlueCove is a little old and doesn't work since Yosemite and I couldn't find any alternative for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use newest version(2.1.2) of Bluecove. It is not officially announced by official Bluecove team but I has native OSX 64 bit support and It could be solution for Win 8. I found this version at [Bluecove issue page](https://code.google.com/archive/p/bluecove/issues/134). Please look under Comment #21. If you want you can download it [here](http://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-attachments/bluecove/issue-134/comment-21/bluecove-2.1.2.jar).